# Content in the text field is cleared on clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, button

```js
function CalcVolume() {
  var radiusvalue = document.getElementById("radius").value
  if (radiusvalue) {
    if (isNaN(radiusvalue)) {
      alert("Provide a number")
      return;
    }

    volumevalue = 4 * 3.14 * radiusvalue * radiusvalue * radiusvalue
    document.getElementById("volume").value = volumevalue;

  } else {
    alert("Provide an input")
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 170px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    Radius<br>
    <input type="text" id="radius">
  </p>
  <p>
    Volume<br>
    <input type="text" id="volume">
  </p>
  <button onclick="CalcVolume()">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

In the above code segment,which is a small logic with UI to calc volume for a given radius, the text fields are auto cleared on clicking the button with text "Calculate".Can someone help me in understanding this?

Comment: I think the issue is that you page is getting submitted.

Comment: Nothing Wrong with the code it is the issue of form is being submit on button click.
just set the button type button and it is fixed.

<button type="button" onclick="CalcVolume()">Calculate</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default type of a `button` is `submit` which is causing the submission of the `form`. Change that to `button`:

`<button type="button" onclick="CalcVolume()">Calculate</button>`

**Working Code:**

```js
function CalcVolume() {
  var radiusvalue = document.getElementById("radius").value
  if (radiusvalue) {
    if (isNaN(radiusvalue)) {
      alert("Provide a number")
      return;
    }

    var volumevalue = 4 * 3.14 * radiusvalue * radiusvalue * radiusvalue
    document.getElementById("volume").value = volumevalue;

  } else {
    alert("Provide an input")
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 170px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    Radius<br>
    <input type="text" id="radius" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Volume<br>
    <input type="text" id="volume" />
  </p>
  <button type="button" onclick="CalcVolume()">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `form` gets submitted.

You can add `onsubmit="return false;"` to `<form onsubmit="return false;">`

Stack snippet

```js
function CalcVolume() {
  var radiusvalue = document.getElementById("radius").value
  if (radiusvalue) {
    if (isNaN(radiusvalue)) {
      alert("Provide a number")
      return;
    }

    volumevalue = 4 * 3.14 * radiusvalue * radiusvalue * radiusvalue
    document.getElementById("volume").value = volumevalue;

  } else {
    alert("Provide an input")
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 170px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <p>
    Radius<br>
    <input type="text" id="radius">
  </p>
  <p>
    Volume<br>
    <input type="text" id="volume">
  </p>
  <button onclick="CalcVolume()">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

---

Or replace the `form` element with a `div`

Stack snippet

```js
function CalcVolume() {
  var radiusvalue = document.getElementById("radius").value
  if (radiusvalue) {
    if (isNaN(radiusvalue)) {
      alert("Provide a number")
      return;
    }

    volumevalue = 4 * 3.14 * radiusvalue * radiusvalue * radiusvalue
    document.getElementById("volume").value = volumevalue;

  } else {
    alert("Provide an input")
  }
}
```

```css
.myform {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 170px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myform">
  <p>
    Radius<br>
    <input type="text" id="radius">
  </p>
  <p>
    Volume<br>
    <input type="text" id="volume">
  </p>
  <button onclick="CalcVolume()">Calculate</button>
</div>
```